# percentages in PostgreSQL with dates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to execute a query where the output is supposed to show the date and a percentage value of how many times the request is a failed request.

the table schema is

[image]

the sample values are

[image]

my query

```
select 
time::timestamp::date, 
(count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from log group by time::timestamp::date))
from log where status like '%404%' group by time::timestamp::date;
```

I am getting an error saying that more than one query has returned by the subquery, how could I make the query to output the percentage on each date value.

I need the output in this format

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select time::timestamp::date,
       avg( (status like '%404%')::int ) as fail_ratio
from log
group by time::timestamp::date;
```

This converts the boolean value into an integer -- 1 for true and 0 for false.  The average then calculates the ratio.

Comment: This is what I want, how can I select the fail_ratio which are greater than 1.

Comment: @juno . . . I don't know what you mean.  The ratio will always be between 0 and 1.

Comment: I multiplied the fail_ratio with 100 to get the percentage value, now I am trying to get the percentage values which are greater than 1 percent.

Comment: @juno . . . Add:  `having avg( (status like '%404%')::int ) > 0.01`.